# Sencha Touch app deployment to IPhone and Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch, extjs

After we build an app using sencha, how do we package it to deploy to physical devices like IPhone and Android. Can we do this in Sencha **only** or do we **have to** use Phonegap or Appcelarator? In stackoverflow there are many articles about this title but little of them are clear. Can't i use only sencha to built an app completely?

Link to any documentation is greatly appreciated.

Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sencha's native android and iPhone packaging.Below i am providing the link for it...

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_android

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_packaging

Comment: If you feel that will help you then should accept the answer so that others can also find it easily.

Comment: @himanshu : am stuck in the deploying process i went through the documention and followed exact steps but when i install .app from itunes in my ios device app is grayed out and title is 'installing' how do i resolve this issue?

Comment: These are dead links